# How to export all product's images using Magento 2 built-in export feature?

Tags: magento2, product-images, export, importexport

I'm managing a Magento ver. 2.4.3-p1 ecommerce.

I tried exporting all our products using the built-in export feature and I noticed that the resulting .CSV only contains each product's base_image and swatch_image.
Since our products generally have around 3-4 images attached, is there a way to export all of them in the .CSV?

[image]

I've noticed there's a configurable option named "Image Gallery" in the export page ("System > Export") but I have no idea if it's related to what I'm looking for, nor how I could try configuring it to check if it works.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra images should have been in the `additional_images` column.

Is this attribute missing from the export, or is it just empty?

Comment: you're right: I made a new export and that column is there with all the other images in it. It was probably an obvious thing but while looking for a solution online I just found many people asking and no clear answers to it.
THANK YOU for your help, much appreciated! :)